# How to add an interaction term in JAGS?

Tags: interaction, model, jags

I'm trying to add an interaction term to a JAGS model. I [found this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21107/interaction-terms-and-bugs) where it shows some interaction terms. But I don't understand what's the guide lines to create an interaction term, which is different than [what's proposed here](https://github.com/jkarreth/Bayes/blob/master/interaction.instructions.R).

I have this code:

```
   for(ind in 1:nind) { ## nind = nrow(d$X)
      for(yr in 1:nyear) {
        logit(phi[ind,yr]) <-
          phi.sp[species[ind]] + ## effect of species 
            phi.year[yr] + ## effect of year
               phi.pc1[species[ind]]*pc1[ind] + ## Effect of morphology, but only the PCA scores
               phi.pc2[species[ind]]*pc2[ind]
of individuals captured)
        } ## (yr in 1:nyear)
```

I want to add an interaction between PC1 and PC2. How should I do this?

```
PC1_2 * pc1[ind] * pc2[ind]
PC1_2 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01) # I want it to be a fixed factor
```

And put these here:

```
for(ind in 1:nind) { ## nind = nrow(d$X)
      for(yr in 1:nyear) {
        logit(phi[ind,yr]) <-
          phi.sp[species[ind]] + ## effect of species 
            phi.year[yr] + ## effect of year
               phi.pc1[species[ind]]*pc1[ind] + ## Effect of morphology, but only the PCA scores
               phi.pc2[species[ind]]*pc2[ind] + 
               PC1_2 * pc1[ind] * pc2[ind]
of individuals captured)
        } ## (yr in 1:year)
```

Is that correct?

Also, is it a good idea to add an interaction between PC axes? Since a scaling 2 would preserve a Mahalanobis distance and focus on correlation between axis and vectors, what would an interaction between a PC1 and PC2 tell?

Comment: I'm surprised by your question since you have sufficient points to suggest that you are familiar with CV. This means that you should know that this site is not intended to be a resource for software specific questions. So, you risk having your question deleted. There are JAGS user groups and support forums. Why not try posting your question there? Alternatively, Stack Overflow is a site for questions like yours. You could migrate it over there.

Comment: I edited my question. It is 1/2 and 1/2 about software and about stats. I was a bit confused where to post it. Since he code is not reproducible and that I'm asking a question at the end about the interpretation of such interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a coefficient of an interaction term that is common to species and years, your code is correct. I don't have much experience of principal component analysis, so I can't answer the latter part of your question, sorry.

Here is my example (for rjags);

```
# I supposed that your data was like this.
#   yr2001 yr2002 yr2003 yr2004 yr2005 ... ind species ...       pc1         pc2 
# 1 Y[1,1] Y[1,2] Y[1,3] Y[1,4] Y[1,5] ...   1       1 ... 0.2543029  0.32230799   
# 2 Y[2,1] Y[2,2] Y[2,3] Y[2,4] Y[2,5] ...   2       2 ... 0.2219234 -0.38741117   
:

model
{

  for(ind in 1:nind) {                   ## nind = nrow(d$X)
    for(yr in 1:nyear) {
      Y[ind, yr] ~ dbin(phi[ind, yr], 12)
      logit(phi[ind,yr]) <-
        phi.sp[species[ind]] +           ## effect of species 
        phi.year[yr] +                   ## effect of year
        phi.pc1[species[ind]]*pc1[ind] + ## Effect of morphology, but only the PCA scores
        phi.pc2[species[ind]]*pc2[ind] + ##  of individuals captured)
        PC1_2 * pc1[ind] * pc2[ind]
    } ## (yr in 1:year)
  } ## (ind in 1:nind)

  for(sp in 1:nspecies){               ## Prior
    phi.sp[sp] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
    phi.pc1[sp] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
    phi.pc2[sp] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
  } ## (sp in 1:nspecies)

  for(yr in 1:nyear){                  ## Prior
    phi.year[yr] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
  } ## (yr in 1:nyear)

  PC1_2 ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)               ## Prior

} ## (end)
```

Comment: Is it faster when you nest the loop like you're doing or if separate for loop is working fine? (I guess it could take longer because you are iterating more times)

Comment: Sorry for my dirty syntax, the prior parts aren't nested. (Is this the answer you were hoping for ?)

Comment: Yep! But also this:   `for(sp in 1:nspecies){## Prior
    phi.sp[sp] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
    phi.pc1[sp] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
    phi.pc2[sp] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
  } ## (sp in 1:nspecies)`
is more efficient than this 
`for(sp in 1:nspecies){    phi.sp[sp] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)  } ## (sp in 1:nspecies)  for(sp in 1:nspecies){    phi.pc1[sp] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)  } ## (sp in 1:nspecies)  for(sp in 1:nspecies){    phi.pc2[sp] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)  } ## (sp in 1:nspecies)`

Comment: Both of them work fine and I can't feel the difference in efficiency.